# Docker for windows issue while installing and running

Tags: docker, installation, windows-10, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have been trying to install Docker for windows in Windows 10 pro edition but I am getting always error in cmd or powershell when I type `docker info` I am getting result like this

`error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/info: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`

I have installed using `InstallDocker.msi` file but not able to fix this issue. I dont have any VM or Virtual Box running and I have make sure that Hyper-V and Virtualisation has been enabled in my PC. Please help me in this issue.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did the installation end successfully with the Docker welcome window?
If not, probably something went wrong during the installation.
You can either reinstall it or try to follow answers in this issue:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22338

Comment: I tried reinstalling several times but I am not able to find out why it's not working? I think any internet firewall may be blocking it. When I tried with my pc it worked but in my office laptop its not working i think may be some firewall issue.